# Should I rely on dynamically loaded assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-assembly

I have the following situation.

- Assembly D contains class `Data`.
- Assembly F1 contains class, which creates, fills and returns `Data`.
- Assembly F2 contains class, which accepts `Data` as input.

The trick is, that all of these assemblies are plugins and are loaded dynamically. Of course both F1 and F2 references D, but in the runtime all three are loaded by host application.

Now what happens if someone replaces D binary file with newer version, which has a different interface?

I wrote a test application, which did something like that, with the following results:

- Adding new field in class Data causes no exception;
- Replacing the existing field with another one results in TargetInvocationException with information, that requested field does not exist

If .NET keeps track of the interface calls, I'm fine. That's because accessing the unchanged part of library will simply work and if that part changes, I'll get an exception simply telling me that. So it will either work (on the interface level) or not - no undefined behavior.

My questions:

- How are the types resolved in the runtime - especially in case of non-matching assembly versions? Does .NET keep track of field/property/parameter/return value types and names?
- Is there a way to force the referenced assembly to be required in some specific version?

Comment: How do you load the assemblies? 'Just' using `Assembly.LoadFrom` or something alike?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes. I'd rather use Assembly.Load, but that doesn't work for assemblies in different folders. Dynamic loading of assemblies is a mess :( It's IMO even worse than DLL hell...

Comment: What about handling the `AssemblyResolve` event?

Answer (score 0):

Your second question: In Visual Studio there is a easy way to force your application to use a specific version of a referenced assembly. Simply click on the assembly under references and look at the properties.  There is a property called "Specific version". If you set it to true and load another at run time, you will get an exception.

Your first question: I don't know exactly how .Net determines, when it is able to use an assembly, that it was not compiled with. So if the signature of a class/interface changes, .Net will throw an exception. *I think* .Net simply tries to use the new assembly and throws an exception if the methods/properties in the class/interface in the new assembly has a modified signature.

Comment: This does not apply on dynamically loaded assemblies. They aren't added through the project references.

Comment: That is a little bit confusing to me. You want to load some assemblies at run-time from lets say a addon folder, so they are unknown at design time. But you want to force them to have specific version?

Comment: I think the question is more about version conflict resolving.

Comment: @user27811 Program loads assembly D and F1. F1 requires D to be in specific version.

Comment: In this case you can force F1 to reference D with a specific version.

Comment: But that is compile time, not runtime.